# Suppressing "Undefined symbol" in Xcode (4)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gcc

I am getting and "Undefined symbol" error while compiling an iPhone app.
I had read somewhere about adding two flags in "Other linker flags" in Xcode project settings but don't remember them now.

Can anyone please tell me what are the flags for suppressing these errors in Xcode?

Comment: I would suggest, that you fix the problem instead of getting rid of the message.

Comment: I am calling a function 'dynamically' from another library. Its basically a jailbroken app. Thats why the function doesn't exist in my app, only a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-force_flat_namespace -undefined suppress` to **Other Linker Flags** in Xcode Build Settings.